# Derivative definition

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Hey I have 2 derivative definition which were told in class.

First one is 
$ \underset{x\rightarrow a}{\lim}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = f'(a) $  This on is pretty straight forward for me.

The second one is 
$ \underset{h\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{f(x_{0}+h)-f(x_{0}-h)}{2h} = f'(x_0)$ this one however isn't clear enough.

The explanation involved something like $\frac{f(x_{0}+h)-f(x_{0}-h)}{h}=\frac{f(x_{0}+h)-f(x_{0})}{h}+\frac{f(x_{0}-h)-f(x_{0})}{-h};$

And $\underset{h\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{f(x_{0}+h)-f(x_{0})}{h}=\underset{h\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{f(x_{0}-h)-f(x_{0})}{-h}=f'(x_{0});$
 (this one is pretty clear to me it's like to substitute $h=x-x_{0}$

Then $\frac{f(x_{0}+h)-f(x_{0}-h)}{2h}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{f(x_{0}+h)-f(x_{0})}{h}+\frac{f(x_{0}-h)-f(x_{0})}{-h}\right)=\frac{1}{2}(2f'(x_{0})=f'(x_{0})$

Now a question in my homework is to express the following expression in terms of $f'(x)$

The expression is :

$$\underset{h\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{f(x_{0}-2h)-f(x_{0}+3h)}{h}$$

Then I try work the expression and get $\frac{f(x_{0}-2h)-f(x_{0}+3h)}{h}=\frac{f(x_{0}-2h)-f(x_{0})}{h}+\frac{f(x_{0}+3h)-f(x_{0})}{-h}$

**Now, is it correct that  $\underset{h\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{f(x_{0}-2h)-f(x_{0})}{h}=\underset{h\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{f(x_{0}+3h)-f(x_{0})}{-h}=f'(x)
 $   ?**

if yes my expression is simply  $2f'(x_0)$  however I am not sure and will appreciate some explanation.

Comment: Incidentally, the "second definition" you learned isn't quite a definition. It agrees with the first when the first exists, but is defined in extra cases.

Comment: Foe example, $|x|$ haa the second definition equal to zero, but the derivative (by first definition) is undefined. The second definition is called the "symmetric derivative". You can find info at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the definition of derivative of a function $f$ defined in a certain neighborhood of $x_{0}$ is given by $$f'(x_{0}) = \lim_{x \to x_{0}}\frac{f(x) - f(x_{0})}{x - x_{0}} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x_{0} + h) - f(x_{0})}{h}\tag{1}$$ The thing to note here is that the derivative of $f$ at $x_{0}$ crucially depends on the value of $f$ at $x_{0}$ i.e. $f(x_{0})$ as well as the values of $f$ near $x_{0}$ (i.e. $f(x_{0} + h)$). So if you want to link any limit with some sort of derivative then you need to identity the point $x_{0}$ and also need to express your limit exactly in the form $(1)$ above.

The second definition is not a definition of derivative, but rather it is a simple theorem:

**A Simple Theorem**: *If $f'(x_{0})$ exists then $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x_{0} + h) - f(x_{0} - h)}{2h} = f'(x_{0})$$*

The proof is as given in your question i.e. you have to bring the $f(x_{0})$ somehow into picture before you can link it with derivative $f'(x_{0})$ and this is done by writing $f(x_{0} + h) - f(x_{0} - h)$ as $$f(x_{0} + h) - f(x_{0}) - (f(x_{0} - h) - f(x_{0}))$$ Note that *the above result does not say anything about the scenario when $f'(x_{0})$ does not exist.*

Next you are asked to calculate $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x_{0} - 2h) - f(x_{0} + 3h)}{h}$$ The only way now is to introduce $f(x_{0})$ also into the picture and we can proceed as follows:
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x_{0} - 2h) - f(x_{0} + 3h)}{h}\notag\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x_{0} - 2h) - f(x_{0}) + f(x_{0}) - f(x_{0} + 3h)}{h}\notag\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x_{0} - 2h) - f(x_{0})}{h} - \frac{f(x_{0} + 3h) - f(x_{0})}{h}\notag\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}-2\cdot \frac{f(x_{0} - 2h) - f(x_{0})}{-2h} - 3\cdot\frac{f(x_{0} + 3h) - f(x_{0})}{3h}\notag\\
&= -2f'(x_{0}) - 3f'(x_{0})\notag\\
&= -5f'(x_{0})\notag
\end{align}
It is important to remember that *if you wish to link any limit with $f'(x_{0})$ then it is essential to first get $f(x_{0})$ and then transform the expression such that some part of it looks like the expression in equation $(1)$.*

**Update**: A more common blunder in such questions is the use of L'Hospital's rule to reduce the fraction $$\frac{f(x_{0} - 2h) - f(x_{0} + 3h)}{h}\tag{2}$$ to $$\frac{-2f'(x_{0} - 2h) - 3f'(x_{0} + 3h)}{1}\tag{3}$$ and then taking limit as $h \to 0$. There are two problems in this approach. First L'Hospital's Rule is a complicated thing and many beginners don't know the exact conditions under which it can be applied and conditions under which it is useful. In the current case we don't know if the function $f$ is differentiable at points near $x_{0}$ like $x_{0} - 2h$ and $x_{0} + 3h$. We are only given that $f'(x_{0})$ exists. Next problem is taking limit of $(3)$ as $h \to 0$ after L'Hospital Rule. This limit will exist only when $f'(x)$ is continuous at $x = x_{0}$. This is also not given in question.

Comment: I appreciate your great contribution!

Comment: Fair enough, it's good that you cleared everything up

Comment: @user313448: I added some more info about not using L'Hospital  in the current question which may be of help to you.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh, Isn't using L'Hopital's Rule, (which is essentially working back from derivatives to find limits), to prove a derivative exists using the formal definition of a derivative, somewhat **circular**. You've taken $\frac{d}{dh}[f(h)]$ in $(3)$, and used that to attempt to evaluate the limit, essentially taking a derivative (albeit with respect to another variable), and used that to prove another derivative exists through the *definition* of a derivative.

Comment: @Perturbative: It seems you read my post too fast. I have specifically warned against the use of L'Hospital in this case. I said that most student commit this kind of blunder when they use L'Hospital in such case. Please read my update again and you will know that we are on same page. And yes I should also have written that L'Hospital should not be used to calculate limits of type $(f(x) - f(a))/(x - a)$ as $x \to a$ because it is circular in this case.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, My apologies, I read your post again, and saw what you said, thanks for clearing that up :).

Answer (score 2):

It is wrong. It should be (for example)

$$\underset{h\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{f(x_{0}-2h)-f(x_{0})}{h}
=-2\underset{h\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{f(x_{0}-2h)-f(x_{0})}{-2h}
=-2f'(x_0).$$

The other is similar, which can be left as an exercise.

Comment: @JeanMarie: yes. Thanks very much! I have changed it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you got the -2 in your first equation?

Comment: I guess : $\frac{a}{b} = -2\frac{a}{-2b}$

Comment: @user313448: Yes, just as davcha said.

Answer (score 0):

To make it as clear as possible, we can separate this expression in a sum of two parts:

$$\frac{f(x_{0}-2h)-f(x_{0}+3h)}{h}=\frac{f(x_{0}-2h)-f(x_{0}+2h)}{h}+\frac{f(x_{0}+2h)-f(x_{0}+3h)}{h}$$

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_{0}-2h)-f(x_{0}+2h)}{h}=4\lim_{2h \to 0} \frac{f(x_{0}-2h)-f(x_{0}+2h)}{4h}=-4f'(x_0)$$

(since $2h+2h=4h$)

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_{0}+2h)-f(x_{0}+3h)}{h}=-f'(x_0)$$

(since $3h-2h=h$)

Finally:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_{0}-2h)-f(x_{0}+3h)}{h}=-f'(x_0)-4f'(x_0)=-5f'(x_0)$$

---

Of course, it makes as much sense to just use: $3h+2h=5h$

Note, that even though this 'derivative' is not symmetric, the displacement is proportional to $h$, so it vanishes in the limit $h \to 0$

To illustrate change the variable $x_0 \to x_0+2h$:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_{0}+2h+h)-f(x_{0}+2h)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} f'(x_0+2h)= f'(x_0)$$

**Edit**

Apparently, this reasoning is flimsy, but at least the limit is correct - see
`http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+h->0+(f(x%2B3h)-f(x%2B2h))%2Fh`

Comment: $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_{0}+2h)-f(x_{0}+3h)}{h}=-f'(x_0)$  could you please elaborate on this one ?

Comment: @user313448, see the latest edit

Comment: There are problems with your approach especially the last equation you have written $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_{0}+2h+h)-f(x_{0}+2h)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} f'(x_0+2h)= f'(x_0)$$ is wrong. This is not how derivatives are defined and used. Even the one which deals with $f(x_{0} - 2h) - f(x_{0} + 2h)$ in the beginning is not automatic, but is justified by the argument given in question.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, I'm aware this is not good, I just wanted to make it easier to undestand. What do you suggest I change?

Comment: I have given the approach in my answer. You need to introduce $f(x_{0})$ here. Also regarding "making it easier to understand", I just want to add that in mathematics you can not sacrifice correctness (although you may sacrifice rigor to some extent depending upon the person whom you are speaking to, and even if rigor is sacrificed it should be mentioned explicitly) for "ease of understanding". Like Einstein said "Make things as simple as possible, but not simpler".

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, but why is the last equation wrong? The middle part is confusing, but am I correct that LHS is equal to RHS? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Well when you want to get from $A $ to $ B$  via a series of steps then each step should be justified and simple compared to the overall equality $A = B$. In your case  we have $A = C = B$ but your step from $A$ to $C$ is invalid as well as $C$ to $B$. Thus the equality $A = B$ is true, but it is not possible to prove it via going to $C$.

Comment: Note that $\lim_{h \to 0}f'(x_{0} + 2h) = f'(x_{0})$ only if derivative $f'(x)$ is continuous at $x_{0}$. This is not given in question and hence $C = B$ is invalid. The trouble with $A=C$ is that there is no specific rule/theorem in math which allows you to go from $A$ to $C$.